# Kotlin new Thread is still running on main thread

Tags: multithreading, kotlin

I am trying to make network calls on a background thread, so I am creating a thread like this:

```
private val networkThread = Thread("NetworkThread")

init {
    networkThread.start()
}
```

However when I try running something on the thread like this:

```
    networkThread.run {
        try {
            socket = Socket(ip, port)
        } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Network Error $e")
        }
    }
```

I get the following error: `Network Error android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Why is this still running on the MainThread? If I create the thread by using a runnable as the param it works, but I am just curious why doing it this way is still counting as the MainThread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`private val networkThread = Thread("NetworkThread")` creates a `thread` which does nothing as you haven't `override` its run method.

```
networkThread.run {
        ....
}
```

`run` method you are using on `networkThread` is not the `run()` method of the `Thread` class but is the `scope` function of `Kotlin` which gives the `context object` as the receiver and returns the `lambda` result, that is why you are getting `Network Error android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

For a `thread` to execute something on the background thread, you've to override its `run` method or you can create a `Runnable` and use it to create `thread` object

```
val networkThread = object: Thread() {
        override fun run() {
            try {
                socket = Socket(ip, port)
            } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Network Error $e")
            }
        }
    }
    
networkThread.start()
```